# Magento2: no CSS style visibility

Tags: magento2

Yesterday I installed the extension and did not see CSS styles.

I ran the command `deploy` and `setup:di:compile` and CSS styles appeared correctly.

Today, I changed the Varnish cache to the built-in cache. I do not see these styles CSS again ... so

I ran again the command `deploy` and `setup:di:compile` and CSS styles now this time in this way not appeared.

Anyone know where is issue?

[image]

Comment: Try to flush the cache and try again. If still not working then manually delete the folder pub/static/frontend and then run setup:static-content:deploy and test again.

Comment: after cache flush no result. Should I delete the entire "frontend" folder or only content manually via FTP?

Comment: yes delete the pub/static/frontend folder from ftp. Then run static content deploy

Comment: I have delete folder frontend and then try again deploy system but still no result :(

Comment: Can you check if the css is generated correctly in your pub/static/frontend folder?

Comment: How can I check it? I see that the frontend folder has been correctly generated. I noticed one thing. When I enable the magento translator on the frontend and change example one word and then accept and  cache flush then restore me some old words (for example in English) which I have already changed before on Polish.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83108/discussion-between-sukumar-gorai-and-sylvester).

Comment: can you tell me which version of magento are you using.?

Comment: @Aakash our version magento is 2.2.3